# Replace the table body using DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm new to using [DataTables](https://datatables.net) and I'v been struggling to change the body of my DataTable.

I have been looking at the API and searching the forum but I could not find anything.

The API has a function called `body()` which is for getting table body. It would have been fantastic if there were a function for setting it.

Imagine I am getting a whole new table body through AJAX and I want to remove the old body and put it instead.

I used to do it by the jQuery function `html()` but looks like things are different here.

Comment: please avoid down votes and attach your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to replace all rows, I would recommend using combination of [`clear()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()) and [`rows.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()).

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.clear();
table.rows.add( [ 
    {
        "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
        "position":   "System Architect",
        "salary":     "$3,120",
        "start_date": "2011/04/25",
        "office":     "Edinburgh",
        "extn":       "5421"
    }, {
        "name": "Garrett Winters",
        "position": "Director",
        "salary": "$5,300",
        "start_date": "2011/07/25",
        "office": "Edinburgh",
        "extn": "8422"
    } 
] );
```

Otherwise, if you want to replace table with HTML content you need to destroy the table with [`destroy()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()), replace `tbody` and then re-initialize the table again with `DataTable()`.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.destroy();

$('#example').html('<thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody>');

table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.destroy();

$('#example').html('<thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody>');

table = $('#example').DataTable();
```